# Запуск приложения в своём приложении

Tags: python, c#, winforms, pyqt

Я хочу написать приложение "Оболочку/Терминал", которое будет при нажатие на кнопку запускать другое приложение в своём окне.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли это сделать?
Если да, то какой framework лучше использовать.
Предпочитаю Python и PyQt. От подсказки по C#  не откажусь, как и от других языков программирования.

Пробовал найти решение в интернете - не получилось

Comment: Добрый день. Врятли такое вообще возможно, в ОС Windows захват окна - уже нетривиальная задача для скрытого окна и возможна лишь в новых редакциях Win10. Тут же помимо перехвата, нужно также полностью передавать команды управления - мышь, клавиатура и прочее, что, опять же, сомнительно что возможно для скрытого окна в принципе. А даже если и возможно, потребуется проделать большую работу с WinAPI и DirectX, в чем вам питон и шарп не сильно помгут

Comment: Можете подумать в сторону протокола RDP и RemoteApp приложений, это чем-то похоже на вашу идею, хоть и по моему опыту RemoteApp в некоторых приложениях показывает очень сырой уровень работы, и не позволяет подключение к локальному хосту (т.е. удаленная работа только)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514706/programs-as-mdi-child-windows